# why is the Formatting Toolbar disabled for CSHTML?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015

Seems like such a simple thing... Visual Studio 2015, an MVC project. Open a View (CSHTML file), I just want to select some text to bold it (wrap selection in a simple HTML "B" tag).

But my Formatting Toolbar is completely grayed out. What gives? Is there no way to HTML format text in a CSHTML page? I can of course type the tags manually but that seems ridiculous.

Comment: Is this an MVC4 solution? or MVC5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no WYSIWYG editor or "designer view" in Visual Studio for Razor (`.cshtml` or `.vbhtml`) files. The formatting tool bar is available when you are in the Design view option for a Web Form (`.aspx` or `.master` file).

You can select the text and right click (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>), then choose Wrap with <div> and then edit "div" to "b" or "strong".

Comment: Marking this as best answer but wow it seems crazy that there is no toolbar / way to one-click-bold text. Developers are definitely formatting text with B and U and I in CSHTML files, so it seems crazy to have the toolbar disabled. C'mon Microsoft.